# How to properly tell FORMAT to discard input

Tags: common-lisp

I want a dynamic way of telling `FORMAT` to discard output depending an a certain global variable set before the actual call. I figured that changing `t` to `nil` should do the deal, but I am not satisfied as I will then not be able to use those `FORMAT` calls at any point where the returned string could be confused for an actual return value.

E.g:

Telling FORMAT to output on TERMINAL-IO (works fine)

```
(let ((*the-var* t))
  (FORMAT *the-var* "some text")
  #|do some other stuff|#)
->"some-text"
->'return-value'
```

Telling FORMAT to discard output (works fine)

```
(let ((*the-var* nil))
  (FORMAT *the-var* "some text")
  #|do some other stuff|#)
->'return-value'
```

Telling FORMAT to discard output (does not work fine as the returned string of FORMAT might get confused with a possible return value)

```
(let ((*the-var* nil)) ;no return value intended//nil expected
  #|do some stuff|#
  (FORMAT *the-var* "some text"))
->"some text"
```

Therefore I wonder if there is any way of telling FORMAT to discard output without to much fuss, like setting the `*the-var*` variable to a *"/dev/null"-stream* or putting a condition-clause around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A broadcast stream with no component streams is the Common Lisp way to discard output. You can create one with [make-broadcast-stream](http://l1sp.org/cl/make-broadcast-stream).

Answer (score 4):

`FORMAT` does not *discard* output.

If you pass `NIL` to `FORMAT` as output direction, then it will return the output as a string and will **not** print to a stream.

The best way to not print anything is to not call `FORMAT`.

It makes very little sense to use `FORMAT` to generate output and not use that output for display. Just check if you want output or not.

```
  (let ((output-p nil)) ;no return value intended//nil expected
    #|do some stuff|#
    (when output-p
      (FORMAT stream "some text")))
```